# Updating large Shapefile with new polygons using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

In QGIS I have a multipolygon layer that has about 100 polygons in it (property boundaries) and I will need to continually add polygons to it as they become available.

What is the most efficient way to merge the smaller polygons into the larger file without creating a new shapefile each time?

Would it be easiest to continue using the merge tool and overwrite the original shapefile?

Each polygon was taken from a large dataset that contains all private properties for the state and each has only one ring. There is very little attribute data with each polygon and the process runs very quickly in only a few seconds.

Comment: You've left out critical details on how you assemble the data, and from what fragments.  A description of the number rings in each polygon and how much attribute data is carried with each is also critical, as is the time it takes for the process to run.

Comment: New to this so I apologize if I don't use the correct terms... each polygon was taken from a large dataset that contains all private properties for the state and each has only one ring. There is very little attribute data with each polygon and the process runs very quickly in only a few seconds.

Comment: You can put the layer into edit mode, select the new polygons, copy and paste them into the layer, then save changes to the layer.

Comment: @csk It can be that easy!? Phew thanks, I'll try that. It's for a forestry company I work for, and I've been tasked with compiling all the data from the past few years into a larger dataset for management purposes... up until this point there has been no "GIS person" at the company so feeling a bit overwhelmed as there is so much data to sort through and organize.

Comment: This method edits the original source file, so if something goes wrong (eg QGIS crashes in the middle of saving the file, or you accidentally delete all the data, then accidentally hit "save edits" instead of "rollback edits"), the original file is damaged. So be sure to make a backup file every so often. Once a day, or once a week, or less, depending on  how often you edit it.

Comment: @csk Yes, I have all of my important files backed-up on multiple devices... I learned the hard way once...

Comment: @CarlaGillean out of curiosity, how many columns of information need to be matched with each merge?

Comment: @DPSSpatial only 15 but I may be simplifying it a bit more going forward, I don't think all are necessary

Comment: @CarlaGillean ok that's quite a bit... though the solution from @ csk above works, I would be very very careful watching how those columns are matched as the features are merged into the destination shapefile... I'm sure resources are limited, but moving into a database such as PostgreSQL with PostGIS makes this process more accurate as you can use SQL to do the INSERTS and explicitly match columns even if the names don't match...

Comment: @DPSSpatial I downloaded PostgreSQL last night but am having some issues figuring out how to use it. Do you know of any online resources that can help me with this? Kind of like a beginners guide?

Comment: @CarlaGillean well there are plenty of resources out there (http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/, etc.) but will take some time and research to get it going if you're brand new. Amazon does make it easy to avoid installation troubles and experiment with the database to get familiar before installing on your own infrastructure: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Welcome.html